# How do I conditionally enable a function based on multiple features enabled?

Tags: rust

I have a library which can be compiled with multiple optional features. I then have a test which I want to conditionally enable when **two** features are both present - i.e. something like:

```rust
#[test]
#[cfg(feature = "dsp-cfft32") AND feature="dsp-rfft1024"]  // This is not correct syntax ...
fn test_filter() {
    // Test which requires *both* the features "dsp-cfft32" and "dsp-rfft1024"
    ... 
}
```

How do write the `#[cfg(...)]` directive to check for both features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the [Conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) section of the reference, you can use `any` and `all` as combinators. So you want to write:

```rust
#[cfg(all(feature = "dsp-cfft32", feature = "dsp-rfft1024"))]
```